# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' and self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1) AssertionError: 0 != 1

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've managed to go up to chapter seven of the book Test-Driven Development in Python.

I have looked into all the threads of the same errors on Google, but the explanations differ from my test case. So I'm struggling to understand what's wrong with the code below. I understand that the

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

tells me `'id'` is not defined. But I don't know where to fix that in Django.

Also for

```
self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1,
```

I don't know where to look.

```
(sup) ben@ben:~/sup1/superlists$ sudo python3 manage.py test lists
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

======================================================================
ERROR: test_redirects_after_POST (lists.tests.NewListTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tim/sup1/superlists/lists/tests.py", line 93, in test_redirects_after_POST
    self.assertRedirects(response, f'/lists/{new_list.id}/')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

======================================================================
FAIL: test_can_save_a_POST_request (lists.tests.NewListTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tim/sup1/superlists/lists/tests.py", line 87, in test_can_save_a_POST_request
    self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

---

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models

class List(models.Model):
    pass

class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, default='', null=True, blank=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

---

TESTS.PY

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.urls import resolve, reverse_lazy
from django.test import TestCase
from django.http import HttpRequest

from lists.views import home_page
from lists.models import Item, List

class HomePageTest(TestCase):

    def test_uses_home_template(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'home.html')

    def test_displays_all_list_items(self):
        Item.objects.create(text='itemey 1')
        # Item.objects.create(text='itemey 2')

        response = self.client.get('/')

        self.assertIn('item', response.content.decode())
        # self.assertIn('itemey 2', response.content.decode())

    def test_only_saves_items_when_necessary(self):
        self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 0)


class ListViewTest(TestCase):

    def test_uses_list_template(self):
        list_ = List.objects.create()
        response = self.client.get(f'/lists/{list_.id}/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'list.html')

    def test_displays_only_items_for_that_list(self):
        correct_list = List.objects.create()
        Item.objects.create(text='item', list=correct_list)
        # Item.objects.create(text='itemey 2', list=correct_list)

        response = self.client.get(f'/lists/{correct_list.id}/')

        self.assertContains(response, 'item')
        # self.assertContains(response, 'itemey 2')


    def test_passes_correct_list_to_template(self):
        correct_list = List.objects.create()
        response = self.client.get(f'/lists/{correct_list.id}/')
        self.assertEqual(response.context['list'], correct_list)


class ListAndItemModelsTest(TestCase):

    def test_saving_and_retrieving_items(self):
        list_ = List()
        list_.save()

        first_item = Item()
        first_item.text = 'The first (ever) list item'
        first_item.list = list_
        first_item.save()

        second_item = Item()
        second_item.text = 'Item the second'
        second_item.list = list_
        second_item.save()

        saved_list = List.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(saved_list, list_)

        saved_items = Item.objects.all()
        self.assertEqual(saved_items.count(), 2)

        first_saved_item = saved_items[0]
        second_saved_item = saved_items[1]
        self.assertEqual(first_saved_item.text, 'The first (ever) list item')
        self.assertEqual(first_saved_item.list, list_)
        self.assertEqual(second_saved_item.text, 'Item the second')
        self.assertEqual(second_saved_item.list, list_)

class NewListTest(TestCase):

    def test_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
        self.client.post('lists/new', {'item_text': 'A new list item'})
        new_item = Item.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(new_item.text, 'A new list item')

    def test_redirects_after_POST(self):
        response = self.client.post('/lists/new', data={'item_text': 'A new list item'})
        new_list = List.objects.first()
        self.assertRedirects(response, f'/lists/{new_list.id}/')

class NewItemTest(TestCase):

    def test_can_save_a_POST_request_to_an_existing_list(self):
        correct_list = List.objects.create()

        self.client.post(
            f'/lists/{correct_list.id}/add_item',
            data={'item_text': 'A new item for an existing list'}
        )

        self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
        new_item = Item.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(new_item.text, 'A new item for an existing list')
        self.assertEqual(new_item.list, correct_list)

    def test_redirects_to_list_view(self):
        correct_list = List.objects.create()
        response = self.client.post(
            f'/lists/{correct_list.id}/add_item',
            data={'item_text': 'A new item for an existing list'}
        )

        self.assertRedirects(response, f'/lists/{correct_list.id}/')
```

---

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
# from django.http import HttpResponse
from lists.models import Item, List

def home_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'])
        return redirect('/')
    items = Item.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def view_list(request, list_id):
    list_ = List.objects.get()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'list': list_})

def new_list(request):
    list_ = List.objects.create()
    Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'], list=list_)
    return redirect(f'/lists/{list.id}/')

def add_item(request, list_id):
    list_ = List.objects.get(id=list_id)
    Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'], list=list_)
    return redirect(f'/lists/{list_.id}/')
```

---

SUPERLIST - URLS.PY

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from lists import views as list_views
from lists import urls as list_urls

urlpatterns = [
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^$', list_views.home_page, name="home"),
    path('lists/', include(list_urls)),
    re_path('^lists/new/$', list_views.new_list, name="new_list"),
    re_path('^lists/(\d+)/$', list_views.view_list, name="view_list"),
    re_path('^lists/(\d+)/add_item$', list_views.add_item, name="add_item"),
]
```

---

LIST - URLS.PY

```
#from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from lists import views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^new/$', views.new_list, name="new_list"),
    re_path('^(\d+)/$', views.view_list, name="view_list"),
    re_path('^(\d+)/add_item$', views.add_item, name="add_item"),
]
```

---

HOME.HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>To-Do lists</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Your To-Do list</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/lists/new">
      <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" />
      {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

LIST.HTML

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}
<body>
  <h1>Start a new To-Do list</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="/lists/{{ list.id }}/add_item">
    <input name="item_text" id="id_new_item" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" />
    {% csrf_token %}
  </form>
  <table id="id_list_table">
    {% for item in list.item_set.all %}
      <tr><td>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ item.text }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
</body>
```

I'm trying to save user input and make sure pages redirect properly but not much success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both cases are due to the fact that no objects exist in the database at the time you are making your assertions.

- In the first case, you are trying to retrieve the `id` attribute on a
  `None` object. Unlike `get()`, `first()` will not
  raise an error but return `None` when no object is found.
- In the second case, you are counting the objects in your database. With no objects there, the count is obviously zero.

These are due to typos:

- in your `new_list()` view. It should be `(f'/lists/{list_.id}/')`, not `(f'/lists/{list.id}/')`.
- in your `test_can_save_a_POST_request`, it should be `'/lists/new/'`, not `'lists/new/'`.
- lack of a trailing slash when calling the POST with the client. `self.client.post('lists/new')` should be `self.client.post('lists/new/')`.

These induce many problems:

- If `APPEND_SLASH` is set to `True` (default), then your request would
  redirect to the URL without the slash as GET, and *may cause any data
  submitted in a POST request to be lost* (Source: [Django Settings
  Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#append-slash)).
- You should use [reverse](https://fikrirasyid.com/attention-to-details-by-zed-a-shaw-of-learn-python-the-hard-way/) for your URLs, that avoids this kind of
  errors and is good practice for not hardcoding the views in general.

So it should be:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class NewListTest(TestCase):

    def test_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('new_list'), data={'item_text': 'A new list item'})
        new_item = Item.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(new_item.text, 'A new list item')

    def test_redirects_after_POST(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('new_list'), data={'item_text': 'A new list item'})
        new_list = List.objects.first()
        self.assertRedirects(response, f'/lists/{new_list.id}/')
```

I ran the project locally with the above modifications, and while some testes would still not pass, your errors were resolved.

One last thing: I don't get why you route the same URLs in the list app (with the `include`) and then again in the project folder. You should just keep the `include`.

I recommend you follow Zed Shaw's advice about [paying attention to detail](https://fikrirasyid.com/attention-to-details-by-zed-a-shaw-of-learn-python-the-hard-way/) ;)

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for your answer. I will look into this. This will take some time before I can get my head around this. Is there a priority order of issues like to handle first?

Comment: I think your explanations are very clear to me as I understand where the problem is coming from in the code. But I still don't know what to put in the List class. I've googled for more than three days but people use different attributes in their classes and I don't know what to call mine. Ex: 'listid' = Item.objects.get(id=id). But this code doesn't work obviously.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that you are creating the objects through POST requests to the views. Will update my answer later today.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pierre.

Comment: I set up the project locally and were able to resolve your errors. See my updates.

Comment: Perfect Pierre, it obviously works here thanks to you! I'll follow all your advice. Thanks for your time and assistance. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I fixed the earlier include and URLs stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help, keep it up!